# How to execute the same curl request on a sequence of server IPs (URLs)

Tags: json, curl, httprequest

**Command**

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
        -X POST -d '{"test": "some data"}' http://XX.XX.X.001:8080/services/test
```

I want to execute the above same curl command on different servers (IP addresses). Is there any way or CURL command so I can execute this service on all servers, instead of changing the IP address every time manually?

I have servers IP in some sequence, e.g.

```
http://XX.XX.X.002:8080/services/test
http://XX.XX.X.003:8080/services/test
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use shell's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) in `bash`, e.g. `{2..15}` for `2,3,4,...,15`:

```
curl ... http://x.x.x.{2..15}:8080/services/test
```

or, `curl`'s [alphanumeric series `[]` operator](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#URL) in the URL part (notice the double-quotes):

```
curl ... "http://x.x.x.[2-15]:8080/services/test"
```

Alternatively, you can use arithmetic `for` loop:

```
for ((i=2; i<=15; i++)); do
    curl ... "http://x.x.x.$i:8080/services/test"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop:

```
for HOST in 0.0.0.1:8080 0.0.0.2:8080; do curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"my": "data"}' http://$HOST/services/test ; done
```

If your hosts are sequential then randomir's answer is a lot cleaner.

Comment: You might want to use an array in this case, for clarity.